# plot points just for each day like error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data that looks something like given below. I want to create a timeseries for each variable A, B, and C with the date on the x axis and `min_val` ,`max_val`, and `Mean_val` as on y axis.

```
mydata <- data.frame(date=c(as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-07"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08"),
                            as.Date("2015-01-08")),
                     var = c("Min_val_a","Max_val_a","Mean_val_a","Min_val_a",
                             "Max_val_a","Mean_val_a","Min_val_b","Max_val_b",
                             "Mean_val_b","Min_val_b","Max_val_b","Mean_val_b",
                             "Min_val_c","Max_val_c","Mean_val_c","Min_val_c",
                             "Max_val_c","Mean_val_c"),
                     val =c(0.01,0.05,0.03,0.04,0.08,0.06,0.06,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.10,0.08,
                            0.07,0.09,0.08,0.08,0.10,0.09),
                     fvar =c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"))
```

I want to plot something like an error line plot with the code below

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=date,y=val))+
  geom_point()+
  #geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~fvar)
```

If I add `geom_line`, then it looks very messy. Is there a way to connect the dots for each day only?

Comment: In SO it is courteous to add a checkmark to an answer if it address most of your points and allows you to move forward. Mouse over the greyed out check below the number beside the answer and click it. Only you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `aes(group = date)` in your `ggplot`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=date,y=val, group = date))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~fvar)
```

[image]